# Is there an established standard for this format of data?

Tags: html, database

This is a bit of a strange question, bear with me: I stumbled upon some data in a machine-readable format in the source code of an HTML page (inside a comment above the opening <html> tag), but I have never seen data that looked anything like this format.

Can anyone identify this data format? Does anyone know if there is an established/documented standard for transmitting/storing data like this? (my hope is that, if this is a standard data format, I can find pre-existing libraries for parsing it and save myself from reinventing the wheel)

Here's the raw data (I omitted some of the data just to keep the post short):

```
<!--
Fin :: 0
ErrorMsg :: 
MoreErrors :: 
MFErrorArray ::  ARRAY[2 * 120]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode]{ }
    [1:ArrayIndex]{ }
MFErrorArray2 ::  ARRAY[3 * 60]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode2]{ }
    [1:Substitution]{ }
    [2:ArrayIndex2]{ }
NotUsed :: 
AllControlNumber :: 
Datu :: 
Pgm :: BXS2BL40
VlNumbHous :: 
NmStrt :: 
NmBoro :: 
VlBin :: 
VlNumbZip :: 
VlTaxBlock :: 
VlTaxLot :: 
VlCensTract :: 
VlHlthArea :: 
HseLo :: 
HseHi :: 
GlJobType :: 
GlPageN :: 0001
GlRecCountN :: 0000000517
FoilIndicator :: 
GlMax :: 
DebugMsg :: 
VlLicnType :: B
NmLicnType :: ELECTRICAL FIRM
VlLicn ::  ARRAY[13 * 70]
[1]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B001572}
    [2:StLicn]{INACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A &amp; A ELEC. CONTRACTING}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000023530}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}
[2]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B002944}
    [2:StLicn]{ACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A &amp; A ELEC&#039;L CONTR&#039;G CORP}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000024858}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}
[3]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B000014}
    [2:StLicn]{INACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A &amp; A ELECTRIC INC.}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000021979}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}
*** I've removed entries 4 through 67 in this array for sake of brevity ***
[68]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B003051}
    [2:StLicn]{ACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A.L. ELECTRICAL CORP.}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000024954}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}
[69]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B002419}
    [2:StLicn]{ACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A.M. ELECTRIC CORP. OF NY}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000024375}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}
[70]
    [0:NmLicn]{}
    [1:VlNumbLIcn]{B003863}
    [2:StLicn]{ACTIVE}
    [3:DtLicnExp]{12312050}
    [4:NmBusn1]{A.M.A HOLDINGS INC.D/B/A}
    [5:NmBusn2]{}
    [6:NbIsn]{0000028205}
    [7:FirmIsn]{}
    [8:FirmLicenseNumber]{}
    [9:JobCount]{0000000000}
    [10:LLicenseClass]{}
    [11:LLicenseClassType]{}
    [12:GreenFlag]{N}

-->
```

Comment: I dont think this is a standard format. Depending on where you got this from, it looks like their own way of storing/documenting/commenting data. Unfortunately it looks like you will have to reinvent the wheel if this is your data source.

Comment: I figured as much; just figured I had nothing to lose by seeing if anyone else had ever encountered this sort of object notation.

Comment: Yeah its definitely their own way of commenting data which is later displayed in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This data excerpt seems to contain information about drivers, vehicles, licensing, etc.

I have not personally seen data formatted exactly this way before, but if you came across it on a commercial website it is likely either a highly specialized data standard for that industry or some ad hoc solution thrown together by that company in lieu of a better standard. Perhaps if you could share a link to the site we could dig into it further, in context.

It looks fairly straightforward though, why not just write a parsing algorithm?

Comment: I found this via [NYC Dept of Buildings Business Search](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/LicenseTypeServlet?vlfirst=N); here is [the specific search I made](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ResultsByNameServlet?bizname=a&licensetype=B&go2=+GO+&requestid=0). I figured I was probably going to have to write my own parsing for it, but it was just weird to me and I was wondering if anyone else had ever seen it. Normally you'd expect just XML or JSON, but this is something else entirely. I'm sure the variable names are arbitrary, but maybe the general notation isn't.